# Execution error in flask python

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to execute the pp function when user send input data from a flask form. But when I click the form submit button some functions in the middle skip(
`os.system(command)`)
and directly render `pp.html` page

```
@app.route('/pp.php', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def pp():
        pp = My1Form()
        target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images/')
        print(target)
        if pp.validate_on_submit():
            for fileNavRover in request.files.getlist("fileNavRover"):
                print(fileNavRover)
                filename = fileNavRover.filename
                destination = "/".join([target, filename])
                print(destination)
                fileNavRover.save(destination)

                c=fileNavRover.filename
                elevation=pp.ema.data
                Freq=pp.frq.data
                posMode=pp.pmode.data                   
                os.system(command)

            return render_template('results.html', email=email_send, Name=pp.Name.data, ema=elevation, frq=Freq, pmode=posMode)
        return render_template('pp.html', pp=pp)
```

I believe this must be a indentation problem but I cant figure out where my problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is proceeding directly to `return render_template('pp.html', pp=pp)`, this can only mean that the line `if pp.validate_on_submit():` returned `False` (i.e. the form did not pass validation).

You can inspect the form errors to find out why validation failed:

```
if pp.validate_on_submit():
    ...
else:
    print(pp.errors) # errors will be printed to the console
```

Comment: As you have mentioned above, I have looked in the flask form validation and I found the problem. I have declared wrong validation fields in the form.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I have included certain wrong validation fields into the flask form. So even though I entered correct values to the form, It always fails to validate

```
class My1Form(FlaskForm):
    ema = IntegerField('Elevation mask angle',[validators.InputRequired(), validators.NumberRange(min=0, max=100)])
```

Proviously `ema` was declared as a text field. So when I tried to enter Integer values, It always fails to validate.

```
@app.route('/pp.php', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def pp():
    pp = My1Form()
    if pp.validate_on_submit():
        target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT)
        print(target)          

        for fileObsRover in request.files.getlist("fileObsRover"):
            print(fileObsRover)
            filename = fileObsRover.filename
            destination = "/".join([target, filename])
            print(destination)
            fileObsRover.save(destination)    

            c=fileNavRover.filename
            elevation=str(pp.ema.data)
            Freq=pp.frq.data
            posMode=pp.pmode.data
            emailAdd=pp.email.data

            chain(processPP.s(posMode,Freq,elevation,a,b,c), emailfile.s(emailAdd), deletefile.s()).apply_async()

            return render_template('results.html', email=pp.email.data, Name=pp.Name.data, ema=elevation, frq=Freq, pmode=posMode, fileBase=a)
    return render_template('pp.php', pp=pp)
```